# How to transfer all the data/memory of a dead Alienware computer into another computer?

Tags: data-recovery, file-transfer, data-transfer

I have an old Alienware M18x, with Windows 8, but it died two weeks ago.

If I buy a new one, will I be able to transfer/download all the data that was inside the memory of the old Alienware into the new one?

What I would like to transfer is mostly:

- Many softwares (mostly chess softwares)
- Many Excel and Word documents
- Many chess games
- Many C# programs
- And also if possible all my things on Firefox (add-ons, favorites, etc) and my desktop wallpapers

Answer (score 1):

It depends what died on your old laptop (laptop right?).

If the hard drive is still good, just take it out and plug it into another computer (desktop probably easiest), then copy over whatever files you want. Documents, files & firefox profiles are easy to copy (google for their usual location in your OS), but installed programs & games may be trickier without the installer to re-install them.

But, if the hard drive is what quit, you may be able to recover some data yet, it may still be mostly readable from another computer, may need a recovery program like `gddrescue` &/or `testdisk`. Note that *if the filesystem is corrupted* **writing anything to the drive may overwrite what you want to recover**, hence `gddrescue` to make a copy first, then recovering from the copy.

Or if it's completely unusable then expensive data recovery companys may be able to still recover some data for some $ (maybe lots of $$$$).